# Error with pre-create check: "This computer is running Hyper-V. VirtualBox won't boot a 64bits VM when Hyper-V is activated

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtualbox, dockerfile, docker-machine

I try to create a docker-machine, like in [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/#create-a-machine)

When I try it, following problem occurs:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "This computer is running Hyper-V. VirtualBox won't boot a 64bits VM when Hyper-V is activated. Either use Hyper-V as a driver, or disable the Hyper-V hypervisor. (To skip this check, use --virtualbox-no-vtx-check)"
```

I am using `Windows 10` and I also try to solve it on [this way](https://jayvilalta.com/blog/2016/04/28/installing-docker-toolbox-on-windows-with-hyper-v-installed/)

by changing the `start.sh` file, but it also does not help.

Does anyone have an idea, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Disable Hyper-V on your Windows machine.
2. Use Hyper-V instead of VirtualBox, if you don't have specific requirements for using VirtualBox (see https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/ for more details)

Comment: Sposiba Dima, 
but is it important for using docker, if I disable it?

Comment: Docker can work with both of them. You just have to choose which one to use.

Comment: Hyper-V feature is not enabled.
Do you want to enable it for Docker to be able to work properly?
Your computer will restart automatically.
Note: VirtualBox will no longer work.

Comment: I get this message, why does the Virtualbox will no longer work without hyper-V?

Comment: Required feature(s) not enabled : Hyper-V.
Docker will exit.

Comment: @Schaumkuesschen, if you prefer to use VirtualBox instead of Hyper-V, I recommend you to start from here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install

Comment: README FIRST for Docker Toolbox and Docker Machine users: Docker for Windows requires Microsoft Hyper-V to run. The Docker for Windows installer enables Hyper-V for you, if needed, and restart your machine. After Hyper-V is enabled, VirtualBox no longer works, but any VirtualBox VM images remain. VirtualBox VMs created with docker-machine (including the default one typically created during Toolbox install) no longer start. These VMs cannot be used side-by-side with Docker for Windows. However, you can still use docker-machine to manage remote VMs.

Comment: I installed docker already, I am not sure, for what does I need the link?

Comment: I can run, download image and so on, just can not use this docker-machine and can not create it